# All test skips on running testNg programmatically

Tags: java, testng

While I try to run testNg programmatically all test are skipping and I am getting an error as Configuration Failure.
Below is the code I used. I that the classes are in a jar file. That jar is added as an external jar in the project.

```
public class ExecuteScript {

    private static void testRunner(Map<String, String> testngParams) {
        TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
        XmlSuite suite = getXmlSuite();
        XmlTest test = getXmlTest(suite);
        test.setParameters(testngParams);
        List<XmlClass> classes = getXmlClasses();
        test.setXmlClasses(classes);
        List<XmlTest> tests = new ArrayList<XmlTest>();
        tests.add(test);
        suite.setTests(tests);
        List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
        suites.add(suite);
        testNG.setXmlSuites(suites);
        testNG.run();
    }
    private static  XmlSuite getXmlSuite() {
        XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
        suite.setName("TestSuite");
        return suite;
    }
    private static XmlTest getXmlTest(XmlSuite suite) {
        XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
        test.setName("test_with_firefox");
        return test;
    }
    private static List<XmlClass> getXmlClasses() {
        List<XmlClass> classez = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
        classez.add(new XmlClass("com.articles.ArticleListingViewTest"));
        classez.add(new XmlClass("com.mynotes.NewNoteCreationDeletionTest"));
        return classez;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        params.put("platformname", "Android");
        params.put("deviceName", "Nexus");
        params.put("OSVersion", "4.2");
        params.put("udid", "4d003e9be03d9");
        testRunner(params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your error stacktrace

Comment: No stacktrace is getting.Only thing i am getting is                               [TestNG] Running:
 Command line suite


===============================================
TestSuite
Total tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Skips: 5
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 5
===============================================

Comment: What's the code in the classes? are there any beforexxx methods?

Comment: @AJESH_M most deffinately there's something wrong in tests and not in the code you've posted

Answer (score 0):

A configuration failure means that a configuration method threw an exception.

Configuration methods are methods annotated with `@BeforeSuite`, `@AfterSuite`, `@BeforeTest`, `@AfterTest`, `@BeforeGroups`, `@AfterGroups`, `@BeforeClass`, `@AfterClass`, `@BeforeMethod`, and/or `@AfterMethod`.

When a configuration failure occurs TestNG skips further tests that depend on the configuration method (unless `@Test` sets `alwaysRun` to `true`).

If you have multiple configuration methods there are several options to determine which one is failing including debugging with breakpoints, adding logging, and using the HTML reports.